# Overload function template based on whether "T" has a member function "myfunc"?

Tags: c++, templates, overloading, type-traits

I want three overloads of a function.

One for `std::vector<T>`, one for any `T` that is a POD, and one for any `T` that has a member function `T::myfunc` (or potentially for all other `T`'s, that would be fine too)

The `vector` is easy.  And I was able to figure out the POD by using `std::enable_if` and `std::is_pod`.  However, I can't figure out how to overload the function for either any other `T` or else all `T` that has `T::myfunc`.

```
#include <vector>
#include <type_traits>
#include <cstdio>

struct S
{
    void myfunc() { printf("S::myfunc\n"); }
};

template<class T> typename std::enable_if<std::is_pod<T>::value, void>::type f(T)
{
    printf("pod\n");
}

template<class T> void f(std::vector<T> const& )
{
    printf("vector\n");
}

// Uncomment to demonstrate non-working version for 'myfunc'
// #define BROKEN
#ifdef BROKEN
template<class T> void f(T t)
{
    t.myfunc();
}
#endif


int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v;
    f(5);
    f(v);
    
#ifdef BROKEN
    S s;
    f(s);
#endif
}
```

Comment: Please show the code you have already written for the first 2 overloads. And if you are fine with the 3rd overload working for all other `T`s just make that overload unconstrained.

Comment: the easiest way to constraint templates is to not constrain them. If your method uses `T::myfunc` then it will already naturally fail for `T` without `myfunc`.

Comment: in any case, please show your code, [mcve]

Comment: added minimal reproducible example

Answer (score 4):

Can also be done with SFINAE:

```
template <typename T>
auto f(T t) -> decltype (t.myfunc(), void())
{
    t.myfunc();
}
```

You might even use one of the detect idiom available on SO, or [`std::experimental::is_detected`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/is_detected) (link provide possible implementation).